# javascript build multidimensional arrays and objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, forms, object

I'm trying to build an array/object based on user-input to a form that has `radio`s, `checkbox`s with `radio`s, `text`fields with `radio`s, and `select`s. I want the final array/object to be consolidated such that activated form-elements with repeated names are collapsed into a single object:

```
data = {
    name0 = (value0,value4), // checkbox
    name1 = (value2), // radio
    name2 = (value5), // select>option
    name4 = (''), // non-response
    name5 = (NULL) // form element was disabled/hidden
}
```

Javascript seems to be rather picky, so I'm having some trouble. I've broken it up into 3 pieces (Arr1,Arr2,Arr3), but it seems like the first bit only retains the last form element and the second bit stops for each name after it's been encountered.

Code in JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/5Y7sn/12/

**EDIT**: What I want the final array to look like for the example in the fiddle is:
*(with all alphas unchecked, beta=1 checked, beta=2 checked, and delta=3 selected)*

```
data : {
    { 'alpha'    : '' },
    { 'beta'     : '1','2' },
    { 'delta'    : '3' },
    { 'continue' : 'continue' }
}
```

*(eventually I'll filter out [continue] using a more precise jQuery selector and put the button outside of a div)*

Comment: It's really hard to understand what exactly you wont to archive with your fiddle but I'm still trying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay.. don't know where to start.. first you should use `:`s instead of `=`s to define the objects properties. Then secondly it's really no problem to nest objects. An attribute of an object can ever by another object. So `var x = { 'a' : { { 1 : {} } : 'the value' } }` is a valid definition.

Further infos when I understood your JSFiddle ^^

EDIT: Here is a possible solution if I understood your question right: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y7sn/8/

Comment: oow, that's almost it, but I want names with unchecked elements to be '' instead of 0 (see the new example I added to my question). Thanks!!

Comment: I think in both of yours, the values of `alpha` and `beta` are being stored as strings instead of arrays/objects: I would expect there to be a comma between `beta:"12"` (where beta=1 and beta=2 are both checked). Besides that, it looks right.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure about your goal here, but I can see some problems with your code:

1. You have a global variable `I`, which is initialised to 0 but never changed so when you use it as an index to `Arr1[I]` inside your `.each()` loop you will continuously overwrite array element 0.
2. You have `Arr2[n] = +1;` when you probably meant `Arr2[n] += 1;` or `Arr2[n]++;`
3. Your for loop uses an undeclared `i` index, though that should work (it's just that `i` is implicitly global, and it's always better to declare all your variables).
4. In the middle of the switch you have `Arr3[nom] += val;` but `Arr3[nom]` is never initialised to 0 so effectively you are saying `undefined += val` which would give `NaN`.
5. In your switch statement you have `case ("checkbox" || "radio"):`, which is equivalent to `case "checkbox"` so you never match on "radio". You want a fall-through to cover both values.

Update your switch:

```
switch(type) {
    case "checkbox":
        // fall-through
    case "radio":
        if (state) {
           if (Arr2[nom] > 1) {
               Arr3[nom] += val;
           } else {
               Arr3[nom] = val;
           }
        }
        break;
    case "text":
        Arr3[nom] = val;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

It is at this point that I agree with @Matmarbon and give up. I'd suggest you fix all of the above and get back to us.

Comment: Whoops, `I++;` must have got deleted at some point (it was at the end of the `.each()`).
#3: I thought the for loop declares `i` and when it does that, `i` only exists inside the loop? (I'm pretty sure that's how it works in php, shell, and C)
#4: I think I need to initialise `Arr3[nom]` as an array and use `push(val)`. 
#5: Doesn't the `()` create a subroutine?

Comment: #2, Arr2[n] holds a count of the number of instances of `n`. ex Arr2["cups"] = 2.

Comment: I've fixed those issues, but now I think I have different ones: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/5Y7sn/23/

Comment: Regarding your comments about the different points I made: #2 yes, I assumed that but you weren't adding 1 to count, you were setting to 1 each time. #3 any variable used without a `var` declaration has global scope, and JavaScript doesn't have block scope like Java or C#, it only has function and global scope. #4 Your code looked like you were trying to keep a sum of the values, but yes if you want to remember individual values then an array and `.push()` would work. #5 No, and even if it did it wouldn't make sense for a `case`.

Comment: Regarding your new fiddle, here's an updated one that runs: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y7sn/27/ I fixed a few problems. Lines 22 & 28 - don't use `var` to create array elements: `Arr2` is already declared so you create a new element with `Arr2[someindex]=somevalue`. Line 38 needed a semicolon rather than a comma (otherwise it tried to treat the if statement that followed as a variable declaration). I think lines 40-44 should be saying `if (Arr3[nom] === undefined) Arr3[nom] = [];` and then just `Arr3[nom].push(val);` otherwise you were never actually initialising that array element to be an array.

Comment: Oh, good to know about js not having block scope—I feel like JavaScript is the Pig Latin of programming languages…. Turns out I was making it too complicated: http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/5Y7sn/26/